# GCC Block Read-Modify-Write for special Variable

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, arm

currently i am working on a project with an ARM M4F on arm-gcc and eclipse.

I have declared bitfields within structs to access the IO-registers. Please see as example:

```
struct abc{
   volatile U32 a:1;
   volatile U32 b:1;
   volatile U32 c:30;
}
```

Now, some of these structs are mappend onto peripherals, which use a set of "Set and Clear" registers.

You write 1U to the Set-Register to set the specific bit and 1U to the Clear-Register to clear the specific bit.

**BUT**
If a bit is set, it is also reflected as set in the Clear-Register for reads.

So `abc_set.a = 1U;` results in `abc_clear.a == 1U`

In my code if have written: `abc_clear.a = 1U;`

**This results in arm-gcc generating:**

```
ldr.w   r0, [r1, #128]  ; 0x80
orr.w   r0, r0, #536870912      ; 0x20000000
str.w   r0, [r1, #128]  ; 0x80
```

The compiler enforces a Read-Modify-Write approach.

**BUT** If other bits are reflected as "1U" in the abc_clear registers, they get also written as 1U and are subsequently cleared as well.

**My question is**

How can i enforce gcc to use a "Write-Only" sheme for specific registers?

I am looking for something like:

```
struct abc{
    #pragma "Only-Write" / or attribute((only-write))
    volatile U32 a:1;
    #pragma "R-M-W allowed"
    volatile U32 b:1;
    volatile U32 c:30;
}
```

Comment: If I understand right you want to write an integer with all but one bit cleared (obviously either most or least significant one depending on how the compiler arranges bits within bitfields). The problem with these bitfields is that they are backed by a single underlying uint32_t. You want to modify one single bit, but for this you need to clear out all other bits. So you need an appropriately prepared single `uint32_t`. No guarantee but I'd try with `abc tmp; tmp.a = 1; tmp.b = 0; tmp.c = 0; abc_clear = tmp;` hopefully resulting in one single write operation.

Comment: I personally would rather get along without bitfields entirely. If you represent the register by a bare `uint32_t` you simply can write `uint32_t(1) << bitIndex` to...

Comment: What ever you decide, encapsulate it.  It can be a `#define` or an `inline set_bit_func()`.  But use something like this.  Trying to use the bitfield pretends that the hardware is just like memory.  This is where many sad stories begin....  It is not memory and even if you get it to work, it may break.  Using some encapsulation will give lots of clues later on that these accesses are special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have declared bitfields within structs to access the IO-registers.

You can't do this with bitfields. Basically, bitfields are not good for this purpose. uP do not have instructions to write or read a few (less than 8) bits only <sup>*</sup>. You wasted your time

You need to do this traditional way

```
#define REG_X_A_POS (0)
#define REG_X_A (1<<REG_X_A_POS)
#define REG_X_B_POS (1)
#define REG_X_B (1<<REG_X_B_POS)

#define REG_X   (*(volatile uint32_t *)0x44006655)
```

And usage:

```
REGX = REG_X_A
```

And the resulting code:

```
foo:
        ldr     r3, .L2
        movs    r2, #1
        str     r2, [r3, #1616]
.L2:
        .word   1140875264
```

When you need RMW you just do it yourself:

```
    REG_X |= REG_X_A;
```

and the compiler will generate the correct code

```
        ldr     r2, .L3
        ldr     r3, [r2, #1616]
        orr     r3, r3, #1
        str     r3, [r2, #1616]
.L3:
        .word   1140875264
```

Another way is to use a temporary variable (not a very convenient way).

```
struct abc tempReg = abc_set;
tmpReg.a = 1;
abc_set = tempReg
```

<sup>*</sup> You can do this using (M4) bitbang areas, but the compiler does not know anything about it.

Comment: `volatile` by itself may not be enough.  The examples work for a single access.  But suppose you have 'turn clock on', followed by 'reset device'.  The code sequence you have are repeated, but the compiler is free to re-order the load/stores.  It may issue the stores back-to-back and the clocking may not be stable in this case.  This is why compiler barriers are also often used... and it is better to have `SET_REGX(REG_X_A);` as an API, where you can add/remove extra functionality as needed by the particular bus interface the registers conform to.  Otherwise, a good answer.